# Access Geoserver layers from a https website

Tags: ssl, https, jetty, geoserver

I have a webapp on internet runing on port 443, so with an url https://site_name.com

I've installed on my windows server 2008 geoserver runing with jetty on port 8080.

But from my website, I can't access my layers from Geoserver.

It returns : 
jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4 GET http://server_name:8080/geoserver/xxx/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&requ…
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Why ?

Is that because my website is in https:// requiering a SSL certificate and my Geoserver at http://server_name:8080 on my server ?
How can I fix it ?

Thanks !

Any help ?

Comment: Do you successfully access to the geoserver administration page from your browser ?

Comment: On the server side yes with http://server_name:8080. Not from my website in https

Comment: did you set the proxy base url in global settings -http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#proxy-base-url

Comment: No @iant, I didn't set the proxy base url. How can I set it ? I don't know what to put in ?

Comment: follow the link in my comment

Comment: @iant, sorry, I've followed your link but I don't understand very well how the proxy works. I have to set the url of my application on internet like https://site_name.com ? Or my Geoserver url accessible on my server http://server_name:8080 ?

Comment: The name of your site

Comment: @iant, I've tried but still doesn't works. My website is running via IIS, maybe it can be a part of the problem ?

Comment: IIS is usually the problem

Comment: @iant, ok. Setting up a reverse proxy in IIS could maybe allow Geoserver to be accessed by my website I suppose ?

Comment: Wondering if this has been solved by just setting the proxy url? Or i have to configure the jetty to enable the SSL?

Comment: @zflaw, yes, following the instructions here https://forums.iis.net/t/1189344.aspx